# Roslyn as a compilation hook/AOP tool

Tags: c#, .net, roslyn

I have been looking through the walkthroughs and documentation for [Roslyn](http://roslyn.codeplex.com/) and there are a lot of examples for things such as IDE-warnings/errors and refactorings, but there appears to be no mention of whether Roslyn can be used as a compilation hook (like byteweaving libraries tend to do, but before we have the generated IL).

For example, I would like to convert:

```
public void DoSomething(Entity e) {
    e.DoSomethingElse();
}
```

to:

```
public void DoSomething(Entity e) {
    using (e.Acquire()) {
        e.DoSomethingElse();
    }
}
```

... But every time the 'before' code is compiled, not as a one-time refactoring.

The meaning of my example is not important, I just wonder if such a thing is possible using Roslyn, and if any examples of such exist?

Comment: so you would like to create something like a "precompiler"?

Comment: @thefiloe Yes, I guess that's what you could call it. Existing AOP libraries use post-compilation (i.e. PostSharp, http://www.postsharp.net/) as far as I know; but it would be neat, I think, to simply add the pertinent code before we pass it to csc.exe.

Comment: [Castle Dynamic Proxy](http://www.castleproject.org/projects/dynamicproxy) can do it at runtime.

Comment: Technically it is of course possible, but expecting full samples like that is kind of a dream, as you can check how much a license of commercial AOP product costs.

Comment: @thefiloe, AOP is kind of "post-compiler", as it usually weaves extra IL instructions into existing assemblies.